# Exception during cache and session cleaning while installing- Zopin live chat extensions in megento

Tags: magento, exception

when i am trying to install Zopim live chat megento extension, i am receiving "Exception during cache and session cleaning". but installed successfully. After installtion with this above error, i tried to open site, its shows "The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later." 503 error. Please help me how to resolve this problem.

Thanks
Bala

Comment: speak with zopim and they'll help you out

Comment: Thank you! Its installed successfully in online. i was trying to local. and i approached Zopim support team. they guided to install it in online. Now its working fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

The error you're seeing means Magento is displaying its default `HTTP ERROR 503` page.  This could be happening for a number of reasons, but most likely it's because the install process (you didn't mention if it was Magento Connect standard, or if it was something else custom) left the `maintenance.flag` file in the site root.  Remove this file from the root of your site, and things should be back to normal.

```
$ cd /path/to/magento/root
$ rm maintenance.flag
```

Comment: Old question and answers, but I'd like to say this also works for Fishpig's Wordpress Magento extension, so it's likely other extensions fail to delete the maintenance.flag file as well.

Answer (score 3):

Prototype.js is missing in the Iframe header of the "console".

Just edit **/downloader/Maged/Connect.php** and find

```
var response = transport.responseJSON || transport.responseText.JSONeval(true) || {};
```

replace it with

```
var response = transport.responseJSON || JSON.parse(transport.responseText) || {};
```

:-)

Comment: This work for me after give permission /var/cache and session...So the question...Why did they leave this like this?